# Get more UARTs with a Shift Register?

Tags: atmega, uart, shift-register

My microcontroller (ATMEGA328) only has one UART. Is it possible to effectively create, say, 8 UARTs with one 8-bit shift register (like a SN74HC595)? The theory would be to send 1 bit from each "virtual uart" at a time to the corresponding bits of the register... Is this doable?

Comment: You would also need a set of 8 latches to "hold" data while the shift register is shifting...otherwise you'd have bits going to "all the wrong places." On transmit, you'd only want to enable data transfer through the latches after shifting complete & on receive you'd only want to enable data transfer through the latches before shifting began. However, I haven't looked up the datasheet for your shift-register yet, and some *do* have this functionality "built-in".

Comment: It's certainly easily doable providing they are all at the same or a power of two multiple baud rate. But why use a shift register when you can simply bit bash serial with an I/O port? There are already libraries available to do this and they'd be easy to convert to multiple serial line applications.

Comment: You could certainly bit-bang 8 *transmitters* that way -- but you'd drive the shift register with a SPI controller, not a UART. Doing 8 asynchronous *receivers* would be a completely different (and much more difficult) matter.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll probably just end up just bit banging on the GPIO. Just wanted to check if this was possible, and I guess since the shift register would be SPI I might as well just bit bang instead.